# input visível ou invisível ao seleccionar checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

O Formulário tem um `checkbox` que ao seleccionar mostra um input que está escondido.

Está a funcionar correctamente, quando entro na página o input está `hidden` e só fica visível quando selecciono a `checkbox`, como mostro:

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
<label for="IniciarTarefa">Tarefa a Par</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="Sim"/>
<div class="form-group input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    </span>
    <select class="form-control" name="Acompnhante" id="Acompnhante" style="display:none" required="" placeholder="Acesso">
      <option></option>
      <?php        
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['id'].'">'.$ln['nome'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#check").click(function(){
if($(this).val()=="Sim"){
$("#Acompnhante").css("display","block");
$(this).val("false");
}
else{
$("#Acompnhante").css("display","none");
$(this).val("Sim");
}
});
```

O problema surge quando insiro na base de dados e com o AJAX limpo esse `input` e a `checkbox` dentro da função `success`, desta forma:

```
$.ajax({
        url: './insertarefa',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){

        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        $('#check').attr('checked', false);
        $("#Acompnhante").val("");
        }
    });
```

Depois de limpar os dois campos com o AJAX, quando selecciono a `checkbox` esconde o `input`, troca o processo, porque quando limpo os dois campos o `input` fica visível. Como posso resolver?

Comment: Não seria pq ficou faltando colocar `$("#Acompnhante").css("display","none");` dentro do `success: { }` ?

Comment: @hugocsl com essa linha de código ao limpar volta a colocar o input `hidden`, mas troca na mesma o processo, só abre quando retiro a selecção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a forma de esconder/mostrar o elemento baseando-se se o checkbox está ou não checado:

```
$("#check").click(function(){

   $("#Acompnhante")[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();

   if($(this).val()=="Sim"){
      $(this).val("false");
   }
   else{
      $(this).val("Sim");
   }
});
```

Veja: se o elemento está checado, chama a função `show()` (mostra), se não, chama a função `.hide()` (esconde). Para isso usei um **[operador ternário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria)** que alterna entre as duas funções:

E no `success`, adicione `.hide()` ao elemento:

```
$("#Acompnhante").val("").hide();
                           ↑
                   esconde o elemento
```

E volte o `value` para "Sim" no checkbox:

```
$('#check').prop('checked', false).val("Sim");
                                    ↑
```

Exemplo:

```js
function simular(){
   $("#Acompnhante").val("").hide();
   $('#check').prop('checked', false).val("Sim");
}


$("#check").click(function(){

   $("#Acompnhante")[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();

   if($(this).val()=="Sim"){
      $(this).val("false");
   }
   else{
      $(this).val("Sim");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">  
<label for="IniciarTarefa">Tarefa a Par</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="Sim"/>
<div class="form-group input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    </span>
    <select class="form-control" name="Acompnhante" id="Acompnhante" style="display:none" required="" placeholder="Acesso">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="simular()">Simular Ajax</button>
```

Comment: só uma questão. Quando selecciono a checkbox e preencho o select, umas vezes insere sim e outras insere falso, quando não preencho insere vazio. Mas quando seleciono o checkbox e preecnho o select, devia inserir sempre sim.

Comment: resolvi desta forma, assim recebo sempre o mesmo valor, troquei isto `if($(this).val()=="Sim"){
      $(this).val("false");` para `if($(this).val()=="Sim"){
      $(this).val("Sim");`, e funciona bem, mas não percebi o porquê de estar acontecer

Comment: Isso mesmo. Já alterei na resposta. Faltou restaurar o value do checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Isto acontece porque você verifica se o valor de #Acompanhante é 'sim', se for qualquer outra coisa ele fica invisível. Você pode performar um evento de clique na checkbox por javascript em vez de setar o atributo dela e o valor do #Acompanhante. Porem acredito que mudar no seu success `$("#Acompnhante").val("");` para `$("#Acompnhante").val("Sim");` ja deve resolver;

Comment: testei da forma que sugeriu, mas o resultado é o mesmo, depois de limpar, troca o processo, porque o problema é que a página não actualiza nem pode actualizar